# How to change legend position using qtm() in the tmap package

Tags: r, plot, maps, tmap

I have created a map of london showing a crime figures. As you can see from my image below - my legend is in a awkward place - i'd prefer it to be on the bottom left or right? anyone know how I could possibly do this. My code that I have created the map with is below.

Also how would i create a title for the map - I have already created the legend title.

## map and legend

[image]

```
qtm(brgh, fill = "Theft15", fill.title="Number of recorded thefts")
```

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not have your data, I decided to use data from the `tmap` package for the following demonstration. The key point is to use `tm_legend()`. If you look into the current CRAN manual, you can find more information in the `tm_layout()` section. You can specify a position of legend using `legend.position` in `tm_legend()`. For main title, you can use `main.title` and `main.title.position` in the function.

```
library(tmap)

data(World, rivers, metro)

qtm(shp = World, fill = "economy", format = "World", style = "col_blind") +
tm_legend(legend.position = c("left", "top"),
          main.title = "My title",
          main.title.position = "right")
```

[image]

```
qtm(shp = World, fill = "economy", format = "World", style = "col_blind") +
tm_legend(legend.position = c("left", "bottom"),
          main.title = "My title",
          main.title.position = "right")
```

[image]